# dark and light areas on car panels

Tags: modeling, mesh, interface

I've just started to use blender to make car models using blueprints, I've run into this problem where i have dark and light areas on the panels for example the top half of the front wing is supposed to be all light and the bottom half is supposed to be all dark. I've already flipped the normals, can someone help me?

[image]

[image: picture of the car I'm modelling]

Comment: You are referring to the lighting artifacts? (Some faces are lit more than others that should be equally lit)

Comment: does that mean that there's something wrong with the mesh?

Comment: It could be a topology issue. Post a close up wire frame screen shot or upload the file.

Comment: Yeah, this is an issue with your mesh, I'm 95% sure about that. Upload your .blend file and I'll take a look at it unless you want to see if you can correct this yourself

Comment: I'll upload it and get some helpful advice from you guys, but i don't know how to upload the file :\

Comment: Go to this link; http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and upload your .blend file there. Then copy your link into your question (Press the edit button below your question). This makes it easy to download your file and it will never expire, to help future people searching for your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that the bottom of the wing has a curve on it, could that be straightened up?

Comment: Just go to edit mode and fix that to your liking. To do this, turn on proportional editing, that way you'll fix the curves in a jiffy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple subdivision surface fixes this:
[image]

This is caused due to some faces being bigger than others, and as such Blender reflects the light differently. This happens when smooth shading is enabled, and the angle/size of two or more faces right next to each other differ greatly.

If using a subdivision surface modifier is not suitable to you (This should work with Blender Game engine as well), modifying the faces may be your best bet.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding the rounded edges that occur upon subdividing, that's easy to fix in edit mode. And if you found my answer useful, please consider marking it as the answer.