# Some of the faces of my model are are dark

Tags: lighting, error

I'm currently creating a car in Blender using blueprints, but I have a problem. Some of the faces are dark and don't interact with lighting.
I thought that I have [this problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86874/dark-and-light-areas-on-car-panels), but sub surf don't work for me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Enter edit mode and press Ctrl N to make normals consistent.

Comment: Ok, I don't know how to thank you. You really saved me.